# How to add to 'Secondary Local Tasks' on Order page

Tags: commerce

Can someone tell me how I can add another item on the Orders page to the existing 'Secondary Local Tasks' which is currently two buttons :- 'Apply Pricing Rules' and 'Simulate Checkout Completion'.

I am overriding page--admin--commerce--orders.tpl.php and would like to add a button to the $secondary_local_tasks variable but can't find where it's set. It's not a menu and isn't in template.php. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just emulate what you see in the other modules:

```
  if (module_exists('commerce_order_ui')) {
    $items['admin/commerce/orders/%commerce_order/edit/refresh'] = array(
      'title' => 'Apply pricing rules',
      'description' => 'Executes the cart order refresh used to apply all current pricing rules on the front end.',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('commerce_cart_order_refresh_form', 3),
      'access callback' => 'commerce_cart_order_refresh_form_access',
      'access arguments' => array(3),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
      'file' => 'includes/commerce_cart.admin.inc',
    );
  }
```

The important thing is the `type` and the `path`.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. In the end I added the code I needed to this template page--admin--commerce--orders.tpl.php after figuring out the order_id etc from the $variables variable.